# DB Connection Timeout simulation

Tags: database, timeout, dbconnection

Is there an way to simulate a db connection timeout?

I'm encountering problems with a timeouted db connection on a productive system and need to simulate a similar situation.

Comment: Can't you just reduce the timeout to something smaller and more managable?

Answer (score 0):

One way that this could be simulated is by killing the connection directly in the database:

Oracle:

```
select * from v$session
where machine like '%machinename%'
order by sid desc

-- SID, SERIAL
alter system kill session '1080,16345'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to a non-existing host or port, and you will get the connection timeout.